# Ajax delete request not working on remote website

Tags: ajax, request, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

Using php with the laravel framework. I have a delete request to delete a file entry on my website, it's working fine locally but on my webserver it's failing.

```
// Ajax call 
$.ajax({
    url: BASE+'/contests/any/entries/any',
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: { 
        entry_id : entry_id 
    },
    success: function() {
        $(".entry-item#"+entry_id).remove();
    }     
});
```

My route:

```
Route::delete('contests/(:any)/entries/(:any)', 'entry@destroy');
```

Controller method:

```
public function delete_destroy() {
    $entry = Entry::find(Input::get('entry_id'));
    Entry::find($entry->id)->delete();
    File::delete(URL::base() . 'public/uploads/' . $entry->filename);
}
```

When I check ajax requests viewing the network tab in chrome developer tools I get a status 404 not found on this delete method while it's working fine locally in wamp. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here and what this 404 not found exactly means?

What exactly isn't found here?

Comment: Just double checking: the URL in the deve tools network tab is the one it should be? And are you absolutely sure your routes.php has been updated on the production server?

Comment: They are all updated and checked at the moment. It seems the delete method is not working for the ajax call because the succes function never even runs. I've changed the ajax type to POST and atleast it will run even though it doesn't post to my proper delete controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `404` not found means that your file doesn't exist and it could be also because of a wrong path and I think it could be because you are using

```
File::delete(URL::base() . 'public/uploads/' . $entry->filename);
```

which returns most probably something like

```
http://yourdomainpublic/uploads/filename
```

Instead, you can use

```
File::delete(path('public').'uploads/' . $entry->filename);
```

Which will output something like this

```
http://yourdomain/public/uploads/filename
```

Comment: I've tested some stuff and it looks like the delete call is never made to the controller so it doesn't matter what's in there at the moment. I will try to update some more.

Comment: `File::delete(URL::base() . 'public/uploads/' . $entry->filename);` should be `File::delete(URL::base() . '/public/uploads/' . $entry->filename);` `URL::base()` doesn't end with a slash. it breaks the url hence.